# Error while running command in Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to execute below given command via terminal:

```
translate bn en < '/home/agnihotri/results/Amader_Malda_4.jpg.txt'
```

The py-translate library is successfully installed.  No matter what ever command I run the error remain the same.

Even for command like `translate en <<< "hello world"`

However, while executing I am getting below given error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/translate/coroutines.py", line
> 170, in spool
>     stream = yield GeneratorExit
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/translate/coroutines.py", line
> 145, in set_task
>     task = yield GeneratorExit
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/translate",
> line 11, in <module>
>     sys.exit(main())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/translate/__main__.py", line
> 115, in main
>     return source(spool(set_task(translate, translit=args.translit)), args.text)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/translate/coroutines.py", line
> 204, in source
>     return target.close()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/translate/coroutines.py", line
> 180, in spool
>     iterable.close()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/translate/coroutines.py", line
> 149, in set_task
>     list(map(stream, workers.map(translator, queue)))   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/translate/coroutines.py", line
> 103, in write_stream
>     sentence, _ = script ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Please help.

Comment: I tried locally and got the same as you, so it seems to be a bug in `py-translate`. I suggest creating an issue on their repository at https://github.com/jjangsangy/py-translate.

Comment: I don't know this library, but the GitHub page mentions that the library is deprecated, and has been so for 2 years. Maybe Google's servers are returning an unexpected answer which triggers that exception. You might want to check that.